# Map not loading anymore in Android app

Tags: android, google-maps

Ive recently generated a new api key for an android application and now it keeps crashing whenever i try to use part of the app that uses google maps.

does anybody know what the problem could be?

ive not changed any code at all it was working flawlessly before i updated the api key.

Thanks.

```
    05-03 00:26:20.699: E/AndroidRuntime(11859): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-03 00:26:20.699: E/AndroidRuntime(11859): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.menuexample/com.example.menuexample.RouteViewActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-03 00:26:20.699: E/AndroidRuntime(11859):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
05-03 00:26:20.699: E/AndroidRuntime(11859):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
05-03 00:26:20.699: E/AndroidRuntime(11859):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
05-03 00:26:20.699: E/AndroidRuntime(11859):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
05-03 00:26:20.699: E/AndroidRuntime(11859):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-03 00:26:20.699: E/AndroidRuntime(11859):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-03 00:26:20.699: E/AndroidRuntime(11859):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
05-03 00:26:20.699: E/AndroidRuntime(11859):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-03 00:26:20.699: E/AndroidRuntime(11859):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-03 00:26:20.699: E/AndroidRuntime(11859):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
05-03 00:26:20.699: E/AndroidRuntime(11859):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
05-03 00:26:20.699: E/AndroidRuntime(11859):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-03 00:26:20.699: E/AndroidRuntime(11859): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-03 00:26:20.699: E/AndroidRuntime(11859):    at com.example.menuexample.RouteViewActivity.setUpMap(RouteViewActivity.java:121)
05-03 00:26:20.699: E/AndroidRuntime(11859):    at com.example.menuexample.RouteViewActivity.setUpMapIfNeeded(RouteViewActivity.java:111)
05-03 00:26:20.699: E/AndroidRuntime(11859):    at com.example.menuexample.RouteViewActivity.onCreate(RouteViewActivity.java:61)
05-03 00:26:20.699: E/AndroidRuntime(11859):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
05-03 00:26:20.699: E/AndroidRuntime(11859):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
05-03 00:26:20.699: E/AndroidRuntime(11859):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
05-03 00:26:20.699: E/AndroidRuntime(11859):    ... 11 more
```

Update:

ok it seems to be a problem with the location manager (returning null) :

```
locMan = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    provider = locMan.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
    loc = locMan.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
```

**Manifest**

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

ok its definitely my locationmanager not getting my location.

any help would be greatly appreciated. im stressing.

Answer (score 1):

Can you see grids in the MapView.If yes then may be you are not getting the location.But if you are not getting that as well and your application crashes,check your manifest for the following

```
<uses-library android:name=”com.google.android.maps” />
```

Answer (score 0):

`getLastKnownLocation` can often return null. You should be using [requestLocationUpdates](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates%28java.lang.String,%20long,%20float,%20android.location.LocationListener%29) in that case.